# PrestaShop backup

Tags: backup

I have a PrestaShop installation on my server and I would like to write a batch script which would make backups of custom data every day.

So far I have only found articles which recommend making a copy of the database contents and of the **complete** directory. I cannot afford to make a copy of all those files every day and I am only interested in backing up **custom data**.

The idea is that should anything go wrong with the production installation, I could simply delete it, do a new clean installation (and possibly some adjustments through the administration GUI) and then fill in custom data from a previous backup.

The question is - **should I backup anything besides the contents of the database**?

When I was doing a similar script for my Redmine installation, I was adviced to backup the database and a single folder where uploaded files are stored. Are there such directories in the PrestaShop application as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/), which uses rsync and hard links to create a snapshot of a filesystem that you can use for an incremental backup.  The advantage of doing this is that you don't need to store a full copy of your data directories in every backup run.

I know absolutely nothing about Prestashop, but I can tell you that only you really can say what you need to backup, and more importantly, what you'll need to restore for business continuity.

Any specific questions about how Prestashop (or any other proprietary or non-distribution packages) should be backed up are best asked directly to the vendor/software author/maintainer.